# How to find a formula for $S(n) = \sum_{d|n} \tau(d)\sigma^2(d)$ in terms of the prime factorization of n.

Tags: number-theory

Let $S(n) =\sum_{d|n}\tau(d)\sigma^2(d)$, where the sum is taken over all divisors d of n.  Find a formula for S(n) in terms of the prime factorization of n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define:
$$f(n)=\sum_{d|n}\tau(d)\sigma^2(d)$$
because $\tau$ and $\sigma $ are multiplicative then $S$ is also multiplicative, so we need only to find the value of $f$ for powers of primes, let $p$ be a prime and $\alpha$ a positive integer then :
$$\begin{align}f(p^\alpha)&=\sum_{d|p^\alpha}\tau(d)\sigma^2(d)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\alpha} (k+1)\left(\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{P-1}\right)^2\\
&=Q_\alpha(p)\end{align}$$
Where $Q_n$ is the following polynomial:
$$Q_n(x)=\frac{(2 + 3 n + n^2)(1-x^2)^2- 4(x+x^3) + 4((2+n)x^{2 + n}+(3+ n)x^{3 +n}-nx^{4 + n}-(1-n)x^{5 + n})-2(2-n)x^{4+2n} + 2(1+n)x^{6+2 n}}{2 (x-1)^4 (1 + x)^2}$$

Hence for every integer $n=\prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{\alpha_i}$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes and $\alpha_i$ are positive integers:
$$f\left(\prod_{i=1}^rp_i^{\alpha_i}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^rf\left(p_i^{\alpha_i}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^rQ_{\alpha_i}(p_i)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. so f(∏i=1rpαii)=∏i=1rf(pαii) is the S(n) in terms of the prime factorization of n? I dont really get the part where we got the f(p^a) and thus n=∏ri=1pαii

Comment: No....never seen that

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you so much !

Comment: but isnt that σ= the sum of [p^(k+1)-1]/p-1 ? how come you just put  σ=p here

Comment: yes you're write but the method still the same, i will check it later!

Comment: I made the calculus by a software and I get the results above. Where did you find this problem?